# Reliably determine file or folder from path?

Tags: python, path, download

Is there a way to reliably determine whether a given path is a folder or a file?

I'm writing a directory downloading tool and I need to determine whether this path is a folder, because folders are traversed rather than downloaded.

Currently I use `pathlib`'s `.suffix` feature, but that is a simple split and breaks on foldernames with periods in them. Another way is to check for trailing slash, which should be fairly reliable on URLs copypasted from the browser, but I'd rather not break on input without a trailing slash.

I guess otherwise I could include a whitelist of acceptable extensions, but holy hacky batman.

EDIT: Example: '/home/ripdog/data/2010.09.19%20%5bFELT-001%5d%20Milky%20Wink%20%5b%e4%be%8b%e5%a4%a7%e7%a5%adSP%5d/'

As you can see, there are 2 periods in there at the start of the final foldername.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using:

`os.path.isdir(name)`

This will evaluate `True` if a given argument is a directory and `False` otherwise.

#### Usage

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isdir(name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it breaks on folders with periods in them as well.

Comment: @Ripdog, Can you provide some examples in your question so that it is easier for us to understand.

Comment: I've added an example path.

Comment: @Ripdog What implementation / version of Python? What system? Perhaps this is an implementation issue. os.path.isdir() has always worked for me, even for paths which include any number of '.'s